# How can i extract administrator from a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} while fetching from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$authors = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT wp_users.user_login, wp_users.display_name,  wp_usermeta.meta_value 
    FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta 
    ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = "wp_capabilities" 
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE "%'.$args['role'].'%" ORDER BY '.$args['orderby'].' '.$args['order'].' ');
```

this is my SQL query and I get a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} but need only administrator.

Comment: [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, just select your role variable as a constant.

```php
$authors = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT wp_users.user_login, wp_users.display_name,  "%'.$args['role'].'%" as role 
    FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta 
    ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id 
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = "wp_capabilities" 
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE "%'.$args['role'].'%" ORDER BY '.$args['orderby'].' '.$args['order'].' ');
```